# Added New Virtualhost to redirect external domain name loads first virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost sub.domain.com:80>
        NameVirtualHost sub.domain.com:80
        ServerName sub.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/colleague/public_html/domain.com/ZendSkeletonApplication/public/

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

        <Directory /home/colleague/public_html/domain.com/ZendSkeletonApplication/public >
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost bugtrack.sub.domain.com:80>
        NameVirtualHost bugtrack.sub.domain.com:80
        ServerName bugtrack.sub.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/colleague/public_html/bugtrack.sub.domain.com/

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

        <Directory /home/colleague/public_html/bugtrack.sub.domain.com >
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost domain2:80>
        NameVirtualHost domain2:80
        ServerName  domain2.com
        DocumentRoot /home/me/public_html

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

        <Directory /home/me/public_html >
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Errors:

```
[Wed Jun 18 18:06:44 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost bugtrack.sub.domain.com:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Wed Jun 18 18:06:44 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost domain2.com:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Wed Jun 18 18:06:44 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

If I go to domain2.com (dummy domain) I reach sub.domain.com . I think that is because the other two virtual hosts have issues. The bugtrack virtual host does load Bug Genie, but the newly added second domain hosted with a third party register does not work and leads to the first virtual host. The final error got added when I uncommented that line in http conf as I thought this would solve the issue.

How can I fix this configuration and make domain2 go to the document root I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your virtualhost definitions

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Ensure that you have a `NameVirtualHost *` too which is **outside** of your VirtualHost context.
[NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) is only allowed in the Server Config [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) e.g.

```
NameVirtalHost *
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/colleague/public_html/domain.com/ZendSkeletonApplication/public/
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I removed the line with `NameVirtualHost` voor the two vhosts after the main one and that works as well and got my third vhost to work as well. Is this an OK solution too or would yours do better?

Comment: It is most common to have the config like this.